# Jenkins slave svn authentication failed

Tags: svn, authentication, jenkins, slave

I have a strange problem with Jenkins and a Jenkins slave. My builds uses the Maven Release Plugin. Project is checked out from a Subversion repository. Later in the build process the Maven Release Plugin tries to commit some changes to my projects pom.xml. It is here the process sometimes fails on the Jenkins slave. Whenever it fails I need to run the build again on the master server before it will work on the Jenkins slave again.

The error I get is: svn failed to authenticate.

I use SVNKit on the Jenkins slave. The same Maven version, and version of other tools, on both master and slave.

Subversion is checked out using svn+ssh protocol. Using public-private authentication without password.

Here is the usecase:

1. Build is running fine on the Jenkins slave
2. Build suddenly begins to fail on the slave.
3. I must run the build on the master.
4. After successful build on the master it can build again on the slave.

This periodic 'bug' is incredibly annoying and it disrupts the release cycle.

To me it seems like some sort of cached authentication is lost somewhere sometimes.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really solved the problem, but I have found a workaround. It seems like the Maven Release Plugin will not use the private key when invoking svn with ssh+svn. It will only work on the slave, in some cases, when the build has run on the master node and then afterwards on the slave node.

Workaround; when using the Maven Release Plugin on a Jenkins slave node use the arguments -Dusername and -Dpassword. It is not a pretty fix, but it works.